# How to transfer layer data from OpenLayers to PostGIS database or QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, postgis, layers, database

Supposing I have a created some layers in OpenLayers containing only Geometry Points, how do I transfer my data to a postGIS database?

Is there a way to turn pure javascript/openlayers to a table in my database fast?

Or maybe transfer them first in QGIS?

Comment: Where did the data come from that you want to save? The user creating it? Or was it from a JSON file, KML or other source?

Comment: @MarkC The data are some Geometry Points I created by hand. I checked the lon lat from OpenStreetMap and I entered them into Geometry Points,turned the Geometry Points into Features and then into Layers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `write` function of the [OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/lib/OpenLayers/Format/GeoJSON.js#L449) to generate (Geo)JSON directly. The input is either an `OpenLayers` geometry, feature or feature vector, so the returned JSON, will either contain one or many features depending on the input. Note if your OpenLayers Features have attributes, these get turned into JSON too, so you can use this to save state, such as Polygon formatting.

```
var writer = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON();
var geojson = writer.write(feat);
```

Note there is a second parameter, pretty, which defaults to false, which will give you nicely formatted JSON (useful for debugging, but not for putting in a db).

A lot depends on how you want to map your OpenLayers features to Postgis. You can save the JSON directly as a Postgres text type. You either put an entire feature collection into a single text field or you could save each geometry separately -- this really depends on how you send data to the GeoJSON.write function in the first place.

Postgres will have a binary JSON representation known as [JSONB](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html) -- Postgres 9.4 is currently in beta. This will allow you to index JSON stored in Postgres using a GIN index, should you need to. You will continue to be able to store JSON as a text datatype should you wish to. There is a good explanation of JSON vs JSONB in [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22654170/explanation-of-jsonb-introduced-by-postgresql).

To get data out of Postgis and back into OpenLayers, you just select the JSON and load it using the `read` function of `OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON`.

Clearly you will need some server-side code to do actually take the GeoJSON and do the insert/select to/from Postgres.

**EDIT**: The answer above deals with saving JSON, as is, which can be used to serialize/deserialize OpenLayers features. It is worth mentioning that if you want to save the data as geometry objects in Postgis, which you can then index and do further spatial analysis on, there is also the `OpenLayers.Format.WKT` class which will allow you to save your geometries as well-known text, which you can then insert into PostGIS with the [ST_GeomFromText](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html) function. Finally, there is the [ST_GeomFromGeoJSON](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoJSON.html) function, which creates a geometry from GeoJSON.

Comment: Thanks for answering once again! So with the OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON I create a geoJSON layer inside the javascrpt function and then I take it from there with a server side language and save it to the database? Couldn't I use the GeoServer for the saving part?

Comment: You could use a WFS-T (which supports CRUD operations) call to update a geometry via Geoserver, but I think the source would have to be GeoServer in the first place. However, if you are interested in saving JSON, as is, (possibly with attributes too) and easily loading/saving from a db field, then what I have suggested might be easier.

Comment: Thanks, as I am a newbie, I will start reading about this stuff now. Which server side language would be best for that job? Could Django framework be used?

Comment: I'm sure Django would be perfect, I have never used it, but use Python for all sorts of other things. There are plenty of other options, Java, PHP, etc, but really no reason to look beyond Python/Django.

Comment: Is this the best way to save user input too?

Comment: Can I use node.js ?

Comment: Yes, node.js would be perfect, if you are comfortable working with it, there is no need to change.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include more info on saving geometries (rather than entire JSON objects) in Postgis.

Comment: I having a really hard time understanding all this!   I can't understand how I am going to insert the geojson or WKT into the POSTGIS. Should I ask another question or can you guide me through this from here? Should I use a server side language?

Comment: Yes, you need to use a server side language, as you can't write directly to db from client side js. insert into sometable (geom) values (st_geomfromtext(wkt)); kind of thing will insert your wkt as a geometry.

Comment: What about this question? http://bit.ly/ZBb9uT .Couldn't I save it this way to GeoServer and from there to my database? This way is not programmatical I think, right?